# Why can't set the random color?

Tags: java, android, random, colors

## Description

**Tool:**
Android 4.2+, Jelly Bean, API level 17

I started android programming a couple of hours ago and I can set a random text, but the color don't changing (text and background, too). I use the same logic, what was right at the text modifying, but something went wrong.

### Activity content

[image: Activity Content]

### ColorWheel content

[image: ColorWheel Content]

Comment: it's better to put code here, not using image :D

Comment: post your code not pics ... it's really weird that the color doesn't change ... the codes look fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I tested on an AVD device, and it's working! I don't understand this.... my phone will be crash or stupid?? (I really care the correct API level, so I don't know what's the problem..)

**But the point is the code is right.
Thanks for helping!**

P.S.: next time i will use the code, not the picture.

Comment: After, I manually deleted the app, then reinstall it works correctly.
**Problem solved**!